# Specific match with "OR condition" - regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a regex to match `datetime` with these formats:

```
d/M/yyyy
d-M-yyyy
M/d/yyyy
M-d-yyyy
dd/MM/yyyy
dd-MM-yyyy
MM/dd/yyyy
MM-dd-yyyy
...
```

I've tried:

```js
var reg = /^(\d{1,4}[/\-]\d{1,2}[/\-]\d{1,4}\s(\d{1,2}:){2}\d{1,2})$/;
alert(reg.test('18/07/2016 00:00:00'));
```

It works fine. But the problem is: it still works with this format:

```
d/M-yyyy

//or

dd-MM/yyyy
```

I saw the index of the problem is in `[/\-]`. I need it's duplicate correct `/` OR `-` (only one).

My question: how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capturing group:

```
^\d{1,4}([/-])\d{1,2}\1\d{1,4}\s(\d{1,2}:){2}\d{1,2}$
```

`\1` will match the same text as what matched the 1st capturing group, which is is `([/-])`.